2020 Moderator Election — Community Interest Check
After our graduation from beta we officially became a full Stack Exchange site. One of the perks of being a full site is the ability to run full-site elections. Elections have been on hold for a while now, but we are curious to see what interest the community has and who would be willing to nominate themselves or be nominated as a candidate for moderator.
To run a full election, we would need at least 4 moderators, to have a competitive election for 3 slots.
We cannot feasibly hold an election without being able to meet these number requirements. 
Our site has never run moderator elections before and everyone serving now is under pro-tem status; the election, if we do indeed run it, would result in properly elected moderators.
Please leave an answer if you'd be willing to run for a moderator position, should we decide to run an election.
NOTE: This is not an official election nomination thread, just a "pulse check" to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up.

RESULT: Thanks to everyone for their support and participation. Please see updates in the latest thread: 2020 Moderator Election. Thanks again!

I'd be willing to run, if we decide to hold an election.

Thanks to some encouraging words, I'd be willing to run.

It appears some kind of "movement" is going on behind the scenes; for unknown reasons, we're officially down to three diamond moderators now, although Alenanno♦ is almost never around nowadays, and Don Kirkby♦ is kind of a sporadic user.  Practically, that leaves only user3306356♦ (i.e., the OP), which isn't a great position to be in.
At the same time, I'm not seeing major issues with moderation as it is (although I don't know what's going on behind the scenes).  Moderation here does not seem anywhere near as pressing as compared to other sites.  (I've spent time at Islam.SE, where debates rear their ugly heads and need urgent moderation, with people insulting other people's religions, etc.)
I want this site to [continue to] be a success, so I suppose I'd be willing to throw my hat in, if it'd help out (and not step on anybody's toes).  But mostly, I'm just here to learn Chinese, so I'm also okay with remaining a non-diamond user.

+1 for the willingness; I'm glad to see it.

Thanks for offering, Becky, and thanks for all your contributions to the community.

Just for clarification: I would be willing to run, if said election actually does take place.
I'd probably need to change my username though...
